# I would like to know how to make automatic refresh instead of pressing a button in Expo/React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, refresh

So I'm new to react native and Expo and i would like to know a way to automatize my screen when i receive an order to update the screen every time.

`My Code:` https://pastebin.com/eqJtay50

Answer (score 0):

you have to send notification to you app each time on server you receive an order ( you can use react-native-firebase...). then in your app, when receive notification, you call api to reload screen ( may use redux-thunk, redux-saga....)